# Imacros eval firefox

Tags: imacros

Currently using Imacros and got a problem, Im using
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
Windows 7
Firefox 44.0.1

Im trying to make something for instagram and Id like if it says follow then it will set the wait time to 30, if it says following it will change the Variable 7 to 0, so far the program will run but it will accept the if statement no matter if it says follow or following and set the wait time to 30, it wont pass it on to the else statement, any solutions?

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
FILTER TYPE=IMAGES STATUS=OFF
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10

URL GOTO=https://www.instagram.com/instagram/ 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !VAR0 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

SET !VAR3 Follow
SET !VAR4 Following

SET !VAR7 EVAL("if (\"{{VAR0}}\" == \"{{VAR3}}\") {VAR7= 5;} else {VAR7= 0;}; ")

wait seconds = {{!VAR7}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow   
wait seconds = {{!VAR7}}
PROMPT EXTRACT:<SP>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR>VAR0:<SP>_{{!VAR0}}_<BR><BR>VAR3:<SP>_{{!VAR3}}_<BR>VAR4:<SP>_{{!VAR4}}_<BR><BR>VAR7:<SP>_{{!VAR7}}_
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `EVAL` statement:

```
SET !VAR7 EVAL("('{{!VAR0}}' == '{{!VAR3}}') ? 30 : 0;")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! Can you explain to me what was wrong with mine?